# Alternative to subclassing LocalValidatorFactoryBean in Spring

Tags: spring, validation

In our code we have implemented a subclass to org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean, overriding validate(Object target, Errors errors) with our own implementation where we run validations, do some extra processing and register error messages.

Upgrading from 3.0 to 3.1, it seems that this method is no longer called. A colleague debugged the spring code and found that it seems that the method with the signature validate(Object target, Errors errors, Object... validationHints) is called instead, and the old validate() is simply skipped. Changing to use the method with validationHints made things work again.

This fix feels kind of weird and prone to future confusion. Is there another way to process validations that is more future-proof?

Comment: @valid annotation does the same rt?

Comment: We are using annotations to mark form parts that should be validated, but we want to add our own extra handling of validation, which is why we're subclassing LocalValidatorFactoryBean.

Comment: I do have the same problem: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?134759-Extending-JSR-303-validation-quot-validate-quot-is-not-invoked-by-Valid-annotation What solution did you chose?

Answer (score 5):

In our project we took a slightly different approach. We are also using Spring 3.1 and we have both beans annotated with validations and custom validations. Our approach may or may not apply to your scenario, because I'm not sure of the method you originally used, prior to the move to Spring 3.1, but here goes.

When we need custom validations, instead of extending LocalValidatorFactoryBean we implement the org.springframework.validation.Validator class. So this implementation executes its own custom code and invokes Spring's default validation, which is exposed via a bean which is autowired into our custom validator. Here is the validator code:

```
@Component("myValidator")
public class MyValidator implements Validator {

@Autowired
private Validator springValidator;

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return MyObject.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object object, Errors errors) {
    MyObject myObject = (MyObject) object;

    // invoke spring default validator so validation annotations are processed
    springValidator.validate(myObject, errors);

    // custom validation
    ....
```

And we have the following bean declared in our spring xml files:

```
<bean id="springValidator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

With the above implementation, the classes that need to invoke validations will do so by invoking validator.validate(Object object, Errors errors). The again, this is why I'm not sure the approach taken in our project applies to yours, since I'm not sure you were using the same validate(Object, Errors) method.

Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a look and see if this works - may be a little while before I can try it. I've seen that we used the Validator interface's validate method before (same as yours, only a subclass or two down the line), and the other validator method that currently works here comes from SmartValidator.